# Time complexity while choosing various pivots in quick sort for sorted, reverse sorted, and repeated elements array

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I have to solve the following question in an assignment:

> Calculate the time and space complexities of the Quick Sort for following input. Also, discuss the method of calculating the complexity.

> (a) When input array is already sorted.

> (b) When input array is reverse sorted.

> (c) When all the elements in the input array are the same.

I am having trouble in calculating the time complexities of the different cases. The following table shows *pivot* vs *case*, with cells in **bold** being the one where I have doubts.

| TIME | First | Middle | Last |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sorted | O(n^2) | O(n*logn) | **O(n^2)** |
| Same | O(n^2) | **O(n^2)** | O(n^2) |
| Reverse | **O(n^2)** | O(n*logn) | O(n^2) |

Are these right? If not, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If the ones you are sure about are correct, then you likely have them all correct.  (The performance of Same depends on exactly how quicksort was coded.)

Answer (score 0):

When all elements are the same, classic Lomuto partition scheme has worst case O(n^2) complexity, while Hoare partition scheme has best case O(n log(n)) complexity with middle value as pivot.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Repeated_elements